# What modules or behaviours I need to implement to achieve the behaviour described?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

### Object Placement serialisation with Unity and Hololens spatial mapping

I'm currently working on an application for Hololens 1 with Unity 2019.4 and MRTK 2.4.0.

I want to know if there is a way to import a spatial mapping into a unity (i have already made a scan of the environment) and use this spatial mapping to place an object with the unity editor at a specific location (like on a table into the spatial mapping).
And then when the application starts the hololens recognize the spatial environment and its place into the environment and place all the objects according to the user position.

**So my question is:** What modules or behaviours I need to implement to achieve the behaviour described above?

I hope I have been clear, I don't want to use Azure spatial anchors or place object when the application run.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask in question form

Comment: Done ,sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Azure spatial anchors, you can achieve similar functions through transfer WorldAnchors. You can refer this link to learn how to use it: [Local anchor transfers in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/local-anchor-transfers-in-unity).

Besides, you also need to instantiate a prefab during runtime and manage the state of the gameobject after import those anchors.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the delay. Thanks for your answer. I choose to use marker with vuforia to instatiate my object at precise location.